# How to add ng-model to dropdown in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have dropdown with two list item Reciever aand beacon.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-state">
     <li ng-class="{active:filterState === 'Receiver'}">
         <a href="" ng-click="updateFilterState('Receiver')">Receiver</a>
     </li>
     <li ng-class="{active:filterState === 'Beacon'}">
         <a href="" ng-click="updateFilterState('Beacon')">Beacon</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

By default selected dropdown item is first one Reciever but i want to add ng-model to it which wil maintain state of it.

I  want this $scope.device to be displayed as by default one like ng-model= 'device'

```
  $scope.$onMessage(Message.deviceType,function(event,deviceType){
      $scope.device=deviceType;
  });
```

How can we do that?

Comment: This's bootstrap dropdown right? Why would you want it to work like select tag? It's just like when user clicks some option in dropdown, action executes which you written on ng-click then you need to show what user clicked? (it's not input field it tend to perform some action). If you still want dropdown & show user the option he selected & perform action on different option selected then that can be achieved easily using conventional select tag input field

Comment: @Shantanu is right, what you need is a select input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a select input here.

```
<select name="devicetype" ng-model="filterState">
      <option value="Receiver" ng-class="{active:filterState === 'Receiver'}"> Receiver </option>
      <option value="Beacon" ng-class="{active:filterState === 'Beacon'}">Beacon</option>
</select>
```